# how to use SQL to alter a field value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

How do I use SQL to flip the value of a bit for rows meeting certain criteria?

For example, my SQL is

```
SELECT * from Attributes WHERE (IsValid = 'TRUE')
```

This query gives me all the records where I want to flip the IsValid bit. Now that I have the rows, I want to flip the bit to FALSE. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Attributes
SET    IsValid = 'FALSE'
WHERE  IsValid = 'TRUE';
```

That what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Use an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE Attributes SET IsValid = 'FALSE' WHERE IsValid = 'TRUE'
```

Note that if the only two possible values for this field are TRUE and FALSE then you are effectively setting all rows to 'FALSE' which is equivalent to not using a WHERE clause (although the performance characteristics may be different):

```
UPDATE Attributes SET IsValid = 'FALSE'
```

Comment: There are a few more conditions that need to be met. But yes, you are correct. In my example all rows will be IsValid = FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
update Attributes set IsValid = 'FALSE' where IsValid = 'TRUE';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Attributes
SET IsValid = 'FALSE'
WHERE IsValid = 'TRUE'
```